# Do I need Redux to display ItemList on the left and ItemContent on the right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Do I really need Redux to manage the app state to achieve this? If not - How do I manage/implement my routes and state for `<ItemList />` and `<ItemContent >/` components?

- Should I create `<ItemsListAndContent />` component and nest other
  components in?
- Maybe this is the case for HOC?

**What's the best
   approach?**

To clarify app structure here is an image:
[image]

### Current case and code:

My app state is passed from `<App />` to `<ExpenseList />`

```
class ExpenseList extends Component {

  const details = passExpenseProps(expense){
    return (
      <div>
        <ExpenseDetails expenseProps={expense} />
      </div>

    )
  }

  render () {
    const {expenses} = this.props;
    const list = expenses.expenseList.map(expense =>
        <Segment clearing key={expense.uid} >
          <a href="" onClick={() => {this.passExpenseProps(expense)}}>
            {expense.createdAt}
          </a>
          <Button floated='right'>
            Preview / Print
          </Button>
        </Segment>
    )

    return (
        <div>

          <Grid celled='internally'>
            <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column width={5}>
                <div>
                  <h1>Your Expense List:</h1>
                  <Button onClick={this.props.loadSamples}>Load Sample Expenses</Button>
                  <Segment.Group raised>

                    {list}

                  </Segment.Group>
                </div>

              </Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column width={11}>
                <Segment>

                  {details}

                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Grid>

      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

this gives me an error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple app, I recommend you avoid redux (and especially if you’re new to react). I would use `react-router` and make a component for each “screen” that has a different url. Store the state in that screen and make all of the other components use props for their data and actions.

For your example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
} from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css';

class ExpenseList extends Component {
    render () {
      const {expenses, selectExpense} = this.props;
      return (
        <div>{expenses.map(expense => (
          <div key={expense.id}>
            <h5>{expense.title}</h5>
            <button onClick={selectExpense(expense)}>View Details</button>
          </div>
        ))}</div>
      )
    }
  }

class ExpenseDetail extends Component {
    render () {
      const {expense} = this.props;
      return (
      <div>
        <h1>{expense.title}</h1>
        <p>${expense.amount}</p>
      </div>
      )
    }
  }



class ExpenseScreen extends Component {
  state = {expenses: [], selectedExpense: null}

  loadSamples = () => {
    // fetch from backend here

    this.setState({expenses: [
      {id: 1, title: "Expense 1", amount: 1},
      {id: 2, title: "Expense 2", amount: 2},
      {id: 3, title: "Expense 3", amount: 3},
      {id: 4, title: "Expense 4", amount: 4},
    ]})
  }

  selectExpense = (expense) => (clickEvent) => {
    this.setState({selectedExpense: expense});
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <div className="expense-container">
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        <div className="left-col">
          <h1>Your Expense List:</h1>
          <button onClick={this.loadSamples}>Load Sample Expenses</button>
          <ExpenseList expenses={this.state.expenses} selectExpense={this.selectExpense} />
        </div>
        <div className="right-col">
        {this.state.selectedExpense && <ExpenseDetail expense={this.state.selectedExpense} />}
  </div>
  </div>);
  }
}


 const About = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>About</h2>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    </div>
  )

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={ExpenseScreen} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you show me your code with react-router-dom for this case? How can you render 2 components on one screen if they are corresponding to different urls?

Comment: Are you suggesting as I'm asking in my post "Should I create <ItemsListAndContent /> component and nest other components in?"

Comment: can you correct my posted code as well? I tried with your solution to fix compile problem but it didn't work. I just want to see and understand the case with my code and the case with react-router.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions!

Comment: I was looking to that react-router example but still can't figure out how to adjust it to my case. I have to pass all the props to my `<ExpenseDetails />` component. Not just id.

Comment: Ok I built a solution that should solve your use case. Let me know if I didn't understand what you were asking

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I needed. I just don't understand this part: `selectExpense = (expense) => (clickEvent) => {
    this.setState({selectedExpense: expense});
  }` what is that clickEvent? too many arrows...

Comment: `selectExpense` is a higher order function which returns another function. It is basically used here to form a closure on `expense` and the `clickEvent` is  the button click event that get in your click handler when you click on a button. `clickEvent` is not used here, so you can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I like `vs1682` answer. It looks less complicated, but I'm not sure how to pass the props via  `onClick`. Is there a way to make my current code to work?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `redux` if your app is simple and small. You can use component states to do that. You should always start small and use redux only when your app grows big enough.

---

Now related your question you can keep your main state in `<ItemList />` component and pass needed data to `<ItemContent />` component based on which item is clicked from the list. Example

```
class ItemList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     ...
     // you can keep your data here like
     // headings and data for the item content
    }
  }

  .
  .
  .
  // your methods
  .
  .
  .
  render() {
    const itemList = //map your list here and
    // provide a click event which will
    // render the respective <ItemContent />
    // may be using an id or some index of the array
    // depends how you want your data structure to be.
    return(
      {itemList}
      // based on which item from the list is clicked
      // you can pass different heading and state
      <ItemContent heading={...} data={...} />
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Edit:** Changes in your code.

```
class ExpenseList extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentItemId = this.props.expenses[0].uid
    }
  }

  handleItemClick = (e) => {
    const uid = e.target.id;
    this.setState({ currentItemId: uid });
  }

  details = () => {
    const { expenseList } = this.props.expenses;
    const [ expense ] = expenseList.filter(expense => {
      return expense.uid === this.state.currentItemId;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <ExpenseDetails expenseProps={expense} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  render () {
    const { expenseList } = this.props.expenses;

    const list = expenseList.map(expense =>
        <Segment clearing key={expense.uid} >
          <a href="#" id={expense.uid} onClick={this.handleItemClick}>
            {expense.createdAt}
          </a>
          <Button floated='right'>
            Preview / Print
          </Button>
        </Segment>
    )

    return (
      <Grid celled='internally'>
        <Grid.Row>
          <Grid.Column width={5}>
            <div>
              <h1>Your Expense List:</h1>
              <Button onClick={this.props.loadSamples}>Load Sample Expenses</Button>
              <Segment.Group raised>
                {list}
              </Segment.Group>
            </div>

          </Grid.Column>
          <Grid.Column width={11}>
            <Segment>
              {details()}
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid.Row>
      </Grid>
    )
  }
}
```

Note: I haven't tested it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you help me out with that onClick event? How do I pass props with onClick to `<ItemContent />`? Updated my post with current code

Comment: @karolis2017 Updated my anwser. Check if it works for you.