# how to pass props to a component via onClick event?

Tags: reactjs

Here I'm iterating through the list and displaying clickable `{expense.createdAt}`. When I click on the `{expense.createdAt}` I want to show its `<ExpenseDetails />` on the same page, so I need to pass the props. How do I do that with onClick?

My code below which doesn't display anything.

```
class ExpenseList extends Component {

  render () {
    const {expenses} = this.props;
    const list = expenses.expenseList.map(expense =>
        <Segment clearing key={expense.uid} >
          <a href="" onClick={() => {this.passProps(expense)}}>
            {expense.createdAt}
          </a>
        </Segment>
    )

    const details = function passProps(expense){
      return (
        <div>
          <ExpenseDetails expense={expense}/>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
        <div>
          <Grid celled='internally'>
            <Grid.Row>
              <Grid.Column width={5}>
                <div>
                  <h1>Your Expense List:</h1>
                  <Segment.Group raised>

                    {list}

                  </Segment.Group>
                </div>

              </Grid.Column>
              <Grid.Column width={11}>
                <Segment>

                  {details}

                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid.Row>
          </Grid>
        </div>

    )
  }
}
```

When I click on`{expense.createdAt}` the page refreshes. This might be an issue. How can I prevent that?

`console.log(this.props.expenses)`:

[image]

Comment: What is `this.passProps`? Please show your entire component.

Comment: I made this up. It supposes to be an action which passes props to `<ExpenseDetails />` and renders `<ExpenseDetails />` component on the screen. I'm  storing this action in `const details`. Does that make sense? I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Is every single element of your code an example? Do you actually have a `Segment` component that has your desired functionality? Are you willing to change the way you structured your current component hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, If I put  `<ExpenseDetails />` instead of  {details} I get the sample text from that component. So it seems works fine. `<Segment>` and others are just semantic-ui style components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. The important concept is that you need to have a parent to both of your subcomponents passing data. In this case, `Expenses` is the parent. In the parent, you create a function, `showItemDetails` that you pass down to `ExpenseList`. That is your clickhandler, which is used to pass back up the index location of the data you want to render. That `showItemDetails` then uses `this.setState` to give `ItemDetails`'s the props you want.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class Expenses extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      expenseItems: []
    }
  }

  showItemDetails(idx) {
    const {expenseItems} = this.props.expenses.expenseList[idx]
    this.setState({expenseItems})
  }

  render() {
    const createdDates = this.props.expenses.expenseList.map(({createdAt}) => {
      return createdAt
    })
    const expenseListProps = {
      showItemDetails: (idx) => this.showItemDetails(idx),
      createdDates
    }
    const itemDetailsProps = {expenseItems: this.state.expenseItems}
    return (
      <div>
        <ExpenseList {...expenseListProps}/>
        <ItemDetails {...itemDetailsProps}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ExpenseList extends Component{
  render() {
    const expenseList = this.props.createdDates.map((date, idx) => (
      <div key={idx}>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.showItemDetails(idx)}>
          {date}
        </button>
      </div>
    ))
    return (
      <div>
        {expenseList}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ItemDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    debugger;
    const items = this.props.expenseItems.map(({uid, date, desc, amount}) => (
      <div>
        {uid}
        {date}
        {desc}
        {amount}
      </div>
    ))
    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I kind of understand what you suggesting but a bit confused. Where do you put `{list}`? With `<Expense /> ` you mean `<ExpenseDetails />`? To clarify my point (end result) please have a look to my previous post. Here is a concept image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46821789/do-i-need-redux-to-display-itemlist-on-the-left-and-itemcontent-on-the-right

Comment: @karolis2017  Ah, I see. What I just showed you doesn't apply to this rendering style. If you're new to React, implementing this can seem very confusing. I can show you how to do it without Redux, but Redux is the more logical approach.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing the code without Redux. It's fairly simple app so don't want to add any more complexity.

Comment: @karolis2017 Please show me a sample of what `this.props.expense` looks like

Comment: You mean the state that I'm passing to `<ExpenseList />`?

Comment: @karolis2017 Yes, whatever you get from `const {expenses} = this.props`

Comment: @karolis2017 Done. I believe I interpreted your data structure correctly, but you might have to make adjustments if I didn't.

Comment: Thanks for this. It all makes sense, but need a bit of time to digest that code.

Comment: @karolis2017 No problem. Yea, the algorithms I use can be pretty confusing. But the important part is passing that function down

Comment: Now the error is pointing to the arrow in this function: `render() {
    const createdDates = this.props.expenses.expenseList.map([date, items] => {
      return date
    });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157112/discussion-between-andrew-and-karolis2017).